# how to modify pcap file for Additional Information in packet

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, packet, tcpdump

### I have one Pcap File which consist of Some Information.

I need to modify the data in the file.

Example:
[image: wireshark details]

As you can see There are details of packets and in **Additional Record** section I have TXT value `fn=Room 110`

Now please help me to change the TXT value

> Example: from `TXT: fn=Room 110` to `TXT: fn=Room 1234`

[image: Example End]

### Things I have Done So Far

#### 1. Used Scapy and Hex Editor To change the Metadata.

with Scapy I have done changes like Changing Destination address or mac address and ports.
But unable to change the TXT records with scapy.

With Hex I am able to change TXT value by converting the String to hex, but I face challenge in different length.

> Example: I can Chnage `TXT: fn=Room 110` to `TXT: fn=Room 123`

> But Can't Change from `TXT: fn=Room 110` to `TXT: fn=Room 1234`
> In this case, the generated pcap gets invalid.

##### Here is a sample working Screenshot Using Python

[image: Python Program]
This code Changes The Destination Mac, Source IP and TXT=Room <value:3 digit>
And That TXT value is being modified by Checking the HEX Value before and after the "TXT: fn=Room" of the packet.

#### Any help regarding this Issue is very very appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: I believe [this post](https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2020/04/modifying-a-packet-capture-with-scapy/) describes step-by-step solution to almost identical problem

Comment: I Tried But didnt work we cannot change TXT values with it also tired changing md length but that didn't work as well.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share sample capture file without any sensitive info? While changing string length, you likely need to update length values in multiple locations like packet data length, specific field length, maybe some data block length etc. But it's hard to say without looking into an actual packet structure.